# reading a .dat file two bytes at a time

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a .dat file, like this:

```
NUL NUL NUL ...
```

So each entry inside this .dat file is a 16-bit signed integer. I want to use C++ to read it two byte at a time. This is currently my code to read it

```
short* ReadData(char* fileName, long imgWidth, long imgHeight, long bytePerPixel)
{
    short * pData = new short[imgWidth*imgHeight*bytePerPixel];
    short h1;
    try
    {       
        std::ifstream input(fileName, std::ios::binary);
        while(!input.eof())    
        {
            //Read file one byte at a time
            input.read(&h1, sizeof(short));
        }
        return pData;
    }
    catch(int i)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    delete pData;
}
```

But it gives me error because

```
input.read(&h1, sizeof(short));
```

reads a byte at a time. I want to read 2 bytes at a time. Is there anyway I can do this? Or what is the best way to read a .dat file inside which there are a bunch of 16-bit signed int? Thanks

Comment: How do you know it reads one byte at a time?

Comment: the ifstream.Read() takes the first argument as char.

Comment: Yes, and the second parameter is the number of bytes that are to be read.

Comment: Which is not likely to be one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` will read however many bytes you ask it to read. But you're not putting the data into your `pData` array. And you need to cast the first argument to `char *`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't understand what you're talking about. `read` reads a block of data.

Comment: `read` reads a block of unformatted bytes, byte by byte.  It's not clear what the OP is asking.  If he wants to read 2 bytes by 2 bytes, then the OS will have to support it (Windows does, but Unix systems generally don't), and he'll have to write a `streambuf` which accesses the desired OS interface.  If he's really looking to convert two bytes (read as bytes) into a two byte value, then he'll have to implement the formatting code somewhere, depending on the format of the two bytes; C++ has no support for binary formats.

Answer (score -2):

do this

```
input.read(&h1,2);  //the number 2 indicates the
                    //number of bytes you are 
                    //reading at a time
```

instead of this

```
 input.read(&h1, sizeof(short));
```

and please **don't use eof()** function because this function is **buggy**
(when i used this function it used to run the loop one extra time ... making my output wrong)

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, and I don't have enough reputation to give you a upvote. Sorry, but thanks for being supportive.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but the condition of `!eof()` doesn't *necessarily* run the loop an extra time; it depends on the formatting of the character sequence.